# How to solve following equation for Gaussian R.V?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, information-theory

Let $y$ is a Gaussian Random variable, how to get the following result?

$ln[\frac {P(y_1 ,y_2 |x=1)} {P(y_1 ,y_2 |x=-1)}]$
$= ln[\frac{1+exp(v_1 +v_2)}{exp(v_1)+exp(v_2)}]$

Where $v_i = 2y_i/\sigma^2$

$i=1,2$ here and $\sigma^2$ is a variance of Gaussian R.V.

Comment: What are $x$ and $P(y_1,y_2\mid x)$?

Comment: $x$ is a given random variable and $P(.)$ is a pmf of Gaussian R.V. Here it is for example when $x=1$ $P(y|x=1) = \frac{1}{\sqrt {2pi\sigma^2}} exp -\frac{(y-1)^2} {2\sigma^2}$